# Moving and resizing shell with mouse (custom titlebar)

Tags: java, titlebar

I want to create custom titlebar so I have to write code that will allow user to resize and move shell (I am using SWT), but I have got problem with

a) capturing mouse up

b) resizing

```
    shell.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(final MouseEvent arg0) {
            move=true;
            oldx=arg0.x;
            oldy=arg0.y;
            Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (move) {
                            shell.setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-oldx, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-oldy);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
            move=false;
        }
    });
```

Moving shell is working *but* it doesn't capture mouse up event. Also I don't know how to make resizing. I have tried

```
shell.setSize(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-shell.getBounds().x, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-shell.getBounds().y);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are expecting event #2 (mouseDown) to fire, before event #1 (mouseUp) has finished firing.  SWT processes events one at a time.  You need #2 to fire to finish operations in #1, which will never happen because #2 will not run.  This is a deadlock situation.  You would need to move the window as the mouse moves, not based on the mouseDown event.  Take a look a this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Compositeinterceptmouseeventsdragabuttonwiththemouse.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the while loop that moves the shell is running synchronously in the UI thread. That will lock the UI and prevent any other events (including the mouse up) from registering.

Try running your movement thread as a separate background thread to allow the `mouseDown` call to return and only wrap the call to `shell.setLocation` in a `Display.getDefault().syncExec`.